# My sharedprefrences not sharing correctly

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have an app where you upload images to my company server 
So The user enters their login details, Email, Password and clientID(4 digit code)(in LoginActivity.java) and then this information must be passed to all the other activities, this passed information is then used to build a URL. Now the issue I am having is the Sharedprefrences doesn't share correctly...they either come up as NULL on the url or as just "email" or "password"
The Information is saved correctly in login activity but when i try to pass it to other activities it fails

**Login activity here I save the prefrences**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {


    SharedPreferences MyPrefs;
    Intent intent;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static final String PREF_NAME= "MYPREFS";
    public static final  String ID = "ClientID" ;
    public static final  String EMAIL = "username" ;
    public static final  String PASS = "password";

    EditText email, password, id;

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Button buttonOne=findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {



                Intent activity2Intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(activity2Intent);

    }
});

        MyPrefs= getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
        editor = MyPrefs.edit();


        email=findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
        password=findViewById(R.id.pwdtext);
        id=findViewById(R.id.clientid);

        email.setText(MyPrefs.getString(EMAIL,"username"));
        password.setText(MyPrefs.getString(PASS,"password"));
        id.setText(MyPrefs.getString(ID, "id"));
        email.addTextChangedListener(this);
        password.addTextChangedListener(this);
        id.addTextChangedListener(this);

        MyPrefs =getSharedPreferences(EMAIL,0);
        MyPrefs =getSharedPreferences(ID,0);
        MyPrefs =getSharedPreferences(PASS,0);
        intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,CameraActivity.class);


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        managePrefs();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
managePrefs();

    }


    private void managePrefs(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =MyPrefs.edit();

        editor.putString(EMAIL, email.getText().toString().trim());
        editor.putString(PASS, password.getText().toString().trim());
        editor.putString(ID, id.getText().toString().trim());

        editor.apply();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
}
```

**Camera Activity this is where the shared prefrences must be passed to**

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final int PICK_IMAGE=12345;
    private final int REQUEST_CAMERA=6352;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_ACCESS_PERMISSION=5674;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    String myURL;
    String email;
    String clientId;
    String pwd;




    private ImageView imageView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
```

**My code for calling sharedprefrences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.PREF_NAME, 0);
         email = sharedPreferences.getString(LoginActivity.EMAIL, "username");
    clientId = sharedPreferences.getString(LoginActivity.ID, "id");
       pwd = sharedPreferences.getString(LoginActivity.PASS, "password");


        imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button fromCamera=findViewById(R.id.fromCamera);
        Button fromGallery=findViewById(R.id.fromGallery);
        Button upload=findViewById(R.id.upload);
        upload.setOnClickListener(this);
        fromCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
        fromGallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {



        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.fromCamera:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            REQUEST_CAMERA_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                } else {
                    getImageFromCamera();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fromGallery:
                getImageFromGallery();
                break;
            case R.id.upload:
                if (bitmap != null)
                    uploadImageToServer();
                break;

        }


    }


    private void uploadImageToServer() {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss");
        String currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(CameraActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Uploading, Please Wait....");
        pd.show();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String Item= intent.getStringExtra("Spinner");
        String Item2= intent.getStringExtra("Spinner2");


        Uri.Builder builder=new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("https")
                .authority("www.smartpractice.co.za")
                .appendPath("files-upload-ruben.asp")
                .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                .appendQueryParameter("ClientID",clientId)
                .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
        .appendQueryParameter("category",Item )
        .appendQueryParameter("client",Item2 );
        myURL=builder.build().toString();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, myURL , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        File imageFile=persistImage(bitmap,currentTimeStamp);

        Ion.with(this)
                .load(myURL)
                .uploadProgressDialog(pd)
                .setMultipartFile("SP-LOG", "image/jpeg", imageFile)


                .asString()


                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                     pd.cancel();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

    }

    private File persistImage(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
        File filesDir=getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
        File imageFile=new File(filesDir, name + ".jpg");

        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os=new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
        }

        return imageFile;
    }


    private void getImageFromCamera() {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    private void getImageFromGallery() {
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
                bitmap=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_ACCESS_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getImageFromCamera();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you called this code lines?
        MyPrefs =getSharedPreferences(EMAIL,0);
        MyPrefs =getSharedPreferences(ID,0);
        MyPrefs =getSharedPreferences(PASS,0);

Comment: I have only been coding for 2 weeks that is my attempt at calling the the information...I really don't know.... :]

Comment: " when i try to pass it to other activities it fails" what is the meaning.You mean ,you cant get value from sharedPreference?

Comment: @Kabir, Yes I use the sharedprefrences to build a URL with URI. builder so when the information is passed I get NULL in my URL

Comment: Check this for sharedPrefernece:https://abhiandroid.com/programming/shared-preference

Comment: @RubenMeiring do you still need help or you solved the issue?

Comment: @Faisal , Yes I have been coding in general for about two weeks, so I am still very uninformed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store data in shared preference do something like this:

```
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("email", email);
                    editor.putString("ID", id);
                    editor.putString("Pass", password);
                    editor.apply();
```

so I'll give you bit of explanation, when you write editor.putString("email", email); it tells editor to put your email against key "email".

Now, if you want to read these values back do it like this:

```
String email = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString("email", "");
String ID= getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString("ID", "");
String password= getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString("Pass", "");
```

Leme know if you don't understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

`getSharedPrerencences(String name, int mode)` returns a reference to a shared preferences file `name`. That is, after the lines

```
MyPrefs =getSharedPreferences(EMAIL,0);
MyPrefs =getSharedPreferences(ID,0);
MyPrefs =getSharedPreferences(PASS,0);
```

your variable MyPrefs points to shared preferences file named `password`, which is probably not what you intended, since later you read from a file named `MYPREFS`.

Also, you don't need to call `editor = MyPrefs.edit();` if you are just reading from the preferences, like you are doing in `onCreate`. That is why you get the warning that you have suppressed using `@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")`

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you are trying to say I am very very new to coding